# I want to Display Popup on tab close in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, cookies

I'm trying to display popup on tab/window close. If user clicks "**leave this page**" so all cookies and session must be cleared/destroyed. Else if he clicks on "**stay on this page**". Everything should be normal as such before ?

My Code :

```
$rootScope.onExit = function() {
  $cookies.remove('isAuthenticated');
  $cookies.remove('current_user');
  $rootScope.isLoggedIn = false;
};
$window.onbeforeunload =  $rootScope.onExit;
```

**My Code is working properly** means if window/tab closed it deletes all cookie but **the problem is i want it to be done after popup result**

Comment: use `confirm` rather than `alert` and have your code run on `OK` click

Comment: @entre stille confirm isn't working at all :(

Comment: can you share the updated code after using confirm...

Answer (score 0):

try to add the code that remove the cookies and the isLoggedIn to unload event and assign an empty function to onbeforeload event

```
$rootScope.onExit = function() {
  $cookies.remove('isAuthenticated');
  $cookies.remove('current_user');
  $rootScope.isLoggedIn = false;
};
$window.unload =  $rootScope.onExit;
$window.onbeforeunload =  function(){}
```